# Update query not working in the script

Tags: bash, sqlite, sh

I want to update the 'Inactive' for selected customer value where their status is active, I tried to do so but it does not update the 'Inactive' for the selected customer. Anyone having any idea what's wrong please let me know. Thanx!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " --- Enter the Database name ---" #name of the database
read databasename

echo " --- enter the table name --- " #name of the table
read table_name

sqlite3 $databasename.db $table_name;

sqlite3 $databasename.db "select * from $table_name WHERE cus_status = 'Active';"

echo "---Select the domain to make Inactive---"
read inactive_user


sqlite3 $databasename.db  "UPDATE $table_name SET cus_status = 'Inactive' WHERE cus_name = $inactive_user $table_name";


sqlite3 $databasename.db "select * from $table_name";
```

Comment: Try putting $inactive_user in single quotes

Comment: sqlite3 $databasename.db  "UPDATE $table_name SET cus_status = 'inactive' WHERE cus_name = '$inactive_user'";                                             Not working

Comment: Why do you repeat `$table_name` at the end of your SQL update query?

Comment: What error are you getting.

Comment: no error ,but the value not changed

Answer (score 1):

Check data type of column `cus_name`. I'm assuming it's `varchar`.
So, instead of `$inactive_user` you may try `'$inactive_user'`

`"UPDATE $table_name SET cus_status = 'Inactive' WHERE cus_name = '$inactive_user' $table_name;"`